# Unable to cast COM object '(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read excel file through this way but getting error:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet;

appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
workbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
// getting error on the below line
worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets;
```

Error is below..

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{000208D8-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

have any idea about this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `workbook.Sheets` is not a type of `Worksheet`.

```
worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets;
```

**UPDATE:**

Sheets is a collection of `Worksheet`, so instead add an index:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet;

worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[0];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: range = worksheet.UsedRange;  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets worksheet' does not contain definition for "UsedRange'

Comment: I think worksheet is a collection. Try adding an index worksheet[0].UsedRange;

Comment: I updated my answer. I guess you can just do it like this so you don't have to change alot on your code.

Comment: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)) on this line 'worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[0]'

Comment: Excel sheet only have one sheet & one column 
UserID
48689
48690
48690
48690
48690
48690
48690
48690

Comment: I suggest you use breakpoints to inspect your code. Check what's wrong with the `workbook`. As far as I know, the casting is now solved. I'm guessing the problem is now with the `Workbook` (how you set it up)